# Environment variables and command line

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have an executable generated from visual studio located at (example) `C:\Projects\SV\Stereo-Vision.exe`. I know I can run this exe file via command line either by (1) navigating to its directory followed by typing Stereo-Vision or by (2) typing out the full/relative path to it depending on what folder I am at.

If I have `C:\Projects` stored as an environment variable under Path, why can't I just type `SV\Stereo-Vision` from wherever I am?

When do environment variables come into play? Do environment variables have to lead to the exe itself? Only then can I just type `Stereo-Vision.exe` from wherever I am?

Comment: It doesn't just append your first command line word to `%PATH%` elements successively, it only searches if you **don't** specify a path. Including `SV/` at the start of your line is like telling the interpreter "don't bother searching, I got this."

Comment: Only the directories directly specified in the `PATH` variable are searched, not their sub-directories.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them